# What does the chorus say in the introduction part of "Livin' La Vida Loca"?

Tags: lyrics

What does the chorus say in the introduction part of "Livin' La Vida Loca" ?

Answer (score 2):

*"Give it a little more volume with the track, please."*

Comment: I'm not a native English speaker. So It's hard for me to listen such a swift line.  
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p47fEXGabaY